# ParaView Clip/Slice, Box Parameters: Meaning of Position, Rotation, Scale; Reconstruct Box in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mesh, triangulation, paraview, rotational-matrices

I want to define a **3D Box** of specific size and location next to a given triangulated **geometry**.

Therefore, I open the geometry mesh in ParaView. Then, I use a **Clip (or Slice) of Type "Box"**. This way I get a ParaView *3D widget* of a box that can be moved, rotated and resized quickly and interactively with the mouse.

The *Property Panel* always shows me the **Box Parameters**:

- Position
- Rotation
- Scale

So far so good, but how can I use these values to work with this box outside ParaView, for example in MATLAB? What are the actual coordinates of the box?

[image: Ventricle Placement Below Atria]

Answer (score 0):

We copy the box properties out of ParaView:

```
box = struct();
box.translate = [-274.8975, -114.0316, -333.6671];
box.rotate    = [27.066, 119.62, -175.472];
box.scale     = [1.031, 0.663, 1.2233];
```

The box size is relative to the size of the geometry the Clip Filter was defined on. So, first get the extent of your geometry, with its vertices stored in `surfpts`.

```
surfpts = ...; % [nPoints x 3]
mn = min(surfpts,[],1); 
mx = max(surfpts,[],1);
```

In this example, I want to fill the box with a grid of points.

```
box.xyz = arrayfun(@(a,b) linspace(a,b,n)', mn, mx, 'UniformOutput',false);
box.xyz = cell2mat(box.xyz);
[X,Y,Z] = ndgrid(box.xyz(:,1), box.xyz(:,2), box.xyz(:,3));
box.XYZ = [X(:), Y(:), Z(:)];
```

Now we have to scale, rotate and translate our grid (in this order!) according to the actions we did to the Paraview box 3d widget.

```
% Scaling
box.XYZ = bsxfun(@times, box.XYZ, box.scale);
% Rotation 
box.XYZ = (rotz(box.rotate(3)) * rotx(box.rotate(1)) * roty(box.rotate(2)) * box.XYZ')';
% Translation
box.XYZ = bsxfun(@plus, box.XYZ, box.translate);
```

Finally, we check the results by opening the created box in ParaView again. It matches exactly with the box.

```
TR = delaunayTriangulation(box.XYZ);
[box_tri, box_pts] = TR.freeBoundary();
vtkwrite('tmp_box.vtk','polydata','triangle',box_pts(:,1),box_pts(:,2),box_pts(:,3),box_tri)
```